# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returning extra urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the current page's URL, then I insert it into a MySQL database. This all works great, but it does something extra that it's not supposed to.

I'm also using an `.htaccess` file to redirect server errors to custom URLs.

The problem I'm having is that when I go to a single page on my website (either from another page of the site or by typing in the URL), `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` logs the page I go to as well as the URL for the 404 Error.

Has anyone ever dealt with this before or know what to do to fix it?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't log anything. What is in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. I'm talking about when it logs `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` into my DB

Comment: Can you post how your '.htaccess' file redirect server error?

Comment: @Fong-Wan this is the line from .htaccess that it's picking up: `ErrorDocument 404 http:../error.php?error=404`

Comment: Ok, that is not the problem, in what file you are using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and MySQL database to log the URL?

Comment: it's in a php file. nothing really special about it. basically the code is (with some code excluded) `$currPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; @mysql_query("INSERT INTO sessions VALUES ('".$session_id."','".$ipAddr."','".$currPage."')");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your 404 line to:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?error=404
```

thus removing `http://...` before `error.php`. This will make sure to forward your 404 URIs to `/error.php?error=404` instead of doing an external redirect hence your original URI will be preserved in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`